# How to fix 'com.example.app15.MainActivity.onCreate' error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create an activity link when the image is clicked. 
I am unable to run the app. It shows 'App keeps closing'. I've searched online and think it's a null pointer exception. Even if it is I can't find the solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        button1=findViewById(R.id.letsgo);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity1();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openActivity1(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at com.example.app3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `private Button button1` to `private ImageButton button1`

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the wrong class. If you want to use Button,then import Button and if you want to use ImageButton,then import ImageButton.Try checking the imported class whether it is  right or not